# If quantity(qty) is greater then 1 so this green update button show otherwise disable. How can I do this in Magento 2?

Tags: quantity, magento2.3.2

[image: so this gr]

If qty greater then 1 so this green update button show otherwise disable. How can I do this in magento2

Comment: using require js ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use simple jQuery code on Click event of Up-Down arrow to make it work.

```
<script>
var qty = jQuery('#qty').val();
if(qty > 0){ 
    jQuery("#product-addtocart-button").attr("disabled", true);
}else{
    jQuery("#product-addtocart-button").attr("disabled", false);
}
</script>
```

Comment: i want when default qty value come from cart page on this first default value button should disable.when we move qty up down button should enable when we come back to default value it should bi again disable. for example default value come from cart page is 5

Comment: THanks its working